# How to install screen-profiles on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, installation, gnu-screen

I have a debian server and want to use the nice screen extension "screen-profiles". I think this comes from Ubuntu.

Is there a way to get it on debian and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, Ubuntu and Debian packages are compatible. So just try installing the .deb from Ubuntu on Debian.

If it complains about dependencies, try to install these from a Debian repo, just to be safe.

You can download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/screen-profiles .

Then just install it as

```
dpkg -i screen-profiles.deb
```

**Edit**

You could also just use the Debian package :-)

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/screen-profiles

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up. The screen-profiles package is now called 'byobu': https://launchpad.net/byobu

Here is the blog post from Dustin about the name change and some of the newly introduced features:
http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2009/05/byobu-20-released-project-formerly.html

Byobu really does make using screen a pleasure :-)

Comment: Notice that for CentOS 7, byobu is available as RPM package from the EPEL repository.